# I got type error issue in pandas read_html(),

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use pandas to read html by using pd.read_html(url), but it always shows the type error. Could you please advice how I can solve it?
I use anaconda3 with python 3.6

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_html('http://isin.twse.com.tw/isin/C_public.jsp?strMode=2',encoding='big5hkscs',header=0)
```

Comment: Well what is not clear about the error: it says that your `encoding=...` can not be processed.

Comment: works fine when I tried it (macOsx, Python3.6, pandas 0.20.1). do you have `bs4`, `xlmd` and `html5lib` installed?

Comment: My python version is 3.6.1(64 bit), and pandas is 0.20.3. I checked my anaconda, it include bs4, xlmd, and html5lib.

Comment: Any chance you're running in a virtual environment that might have different package versions?

Answer (score 0):

try to install html5lib, write in your terminal:

```
pip install html5lib
```

If it isn't working, please verify that you are using anaconda's python, in your IDE check this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and then compare it with input from the terminal command, write it in your terminal:

```
which python
```

the outputs **should** contain the same path.

Comment: I have installed html5lib, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ChenNorman weird it works for me... I updated the answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Pandas added the `encoding` argument to `read_html` in [version 0.15](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/7323).  Check your version with `pd.__version__`.  If it's below `0.15`, upgrade with `conda upgrade pandas` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I check the version, it is 0.20.3.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install or downgrade your html5lib to version 0.999999999

> pip install html5lib==0.999999999

It worked for me